# ¿Cómo mezclar cadenas multilínea que contengan corchetes?

Tags: string, lua

Estoy aprendiendo Lua y se que es posible crear una cadena multilínea usando `[[` y `]]`, es decir, es posible hacer esto:

```
html = [[
  <body>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  </body>
]]
print(html)
```

El resultado sería:

```
<body>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</body>
```

Ahora quiero lo mismo con un ejemplo usando XML y [CDATA](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect), ya que, para efecto de mis pruebas, intento mezclar los corchetes. He definido esto en mi script:

```
xml = [[
  <![CDATA[
    <greeting>
      Hello, world!
    </greeting>
  ]]>
]]
print(xml)
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me genera el siguiente error:

```
lua: test.lua:7: unexpected symbol near ']'
```

Al parecer está confundiendo los corchetes de la línea 6 como el final de mi cadena. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación sobre [Strings en Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial), en la sección **Multiline quotes**, subsección *Nesting quotes*, se explica que cuando necesitas tener corchetes dentro de una cadena multilínea, debes agregar un `=` entre los corchetes de inicio y fin de tu cadena por cada par de corchetes `[]` que se encontrarán dentro de tu cadena. Dado que `CDATA` utiliza 2 pares de corchetes (como se muestra)

```
<![CDATA[
  ^     ^
... contenido ...
]]>
^^
```

Deberás utilizar dos símbolos `=`. Esto es, deberás utilizar `[==[` y `]==]` para definir tu cadena de texto que contiene corchetes. Tu código sería de esta manera:

```
xml = [==[
  <![CDATA[
    <greeting>
      Hello, world!
    </greeting>
  ]]>
]==]
print(xml)
```

Aquí un ejemplo de tu script corriendo en ideone: http://ideone.com/y6YdfK

Comment: ¡Ajá! En la [versión online](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html) de la primera versíon del libro no dicen nada de eso, ya funca.